# Redshift - return different results in different columns depending on criteria

Tags: amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-redshift

I would like to query a table where I will get all the games a player has played and how much money they have bet.

so the records would be something like this:

```
Playerid, Date, Game, GameCategoryId, Bet
```

I would like the result to be something similar to this:

```
Playerid   CategoryId1Bet  CategoryId2Bet  CategoryId3Bet
```

where I would have all the players and all the best in all their separate categories.

```
select playerid,
  case when GameCategoryId = 1 then sum(Bet) end as CategoryId1Bet,
  case when GameCategoryId = 2 then sum(Bet) end as CategoryId2Bet,
  case when GameCategoryId = 3 then sum(Bet) end as CategoryId3Bet
from playertable
group by playerid
order by playerid
```

However this is not working and its requiring me to group by gamecategoryid

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the error message?

Comment: I included the error message before. It wants me to group the gamecategoryid but then i get several rows when in reality i want a row with lots of columns per playerid

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
select playerid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameCategoryId = 1 THEN Bet END) as CategoryId1Bet,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameCategoryId = 2 THEN Bet END) as CategoryId2Bet,
  SUM(CASE WHEN GameCategoryId = 3 THEN Bet END) as CategoryId3Bet
FROM playertable
GROUP BY playerid
ORDER BY playerid
```